# Python: Would it be possible to call a function specifying by string variable?

Tags: python

Given there is a list of function's names as strings, would it be possible to call corresponding function with random sampling from the list? Currently I am hard coding all the name by `if` statement so that

```py
def a(x):
    print(x)

def b(y):
    print(y)
# there are more functions

func_list = ['a', 'b', ...] # all function's names are stored

chosen_function = random.choice(func_list)
if chosen_function == 'a':
    a(1)
elif chosen_function == 'b':
    b(2)
# elif continues...
```

I want to eliminates all if statements so that whenever I add new functions in `func_list`, I do not need to modify the if statements.

However, I can not contain the function itself in the list as the actual functions have randomness in them so I need to call it after the function is sampled.

Comment: "However, I can not contain the function itself in the list as the actual functions have randomness in them so I need to call it after the function is sampled." Could you clarify that?

Comment: You won't call a function by merely including it in a `list`. `func_list = [a, b]` would work exactly the same way as your `if` block.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer of @Jarvis is the right way to go, but for completeness sake, I'll show a different way: inspecting the global variables.

```py
def a(x):
    print(x)

def b(y):
    print(y)
# there are more functions

func_list = ['a', 'b', ...] # all function's names are stored

chosen_function = random.choice(func_list)

globals()[chosen_function](x)
```

Answer (score 3):

Why not use a dictionary?

```
def a(x):
    print(x)

def b(y):
    print(y)

func_dict = {'a': a, 'b': b}
```

Call it like this:

```
x = 3 # your int input
func_dict['a'](x) # calls a(x)
func_dict['b'](x) # calls b(x)
```

If you want to directly specify arguments, you can do so in the dictionary like this:

```py
func_dict = {
    'a': lambda: a(1),
    'b': lambda: b(2)
}
```

Call the default methods like:

```
func_dict['a']() # calls a(1)
func_dict['b']() # calls b(2)
```

Answer (score 0):

You may consider using `eval` function. In a nutshell, it evaluates a string into a Python snippet.

For example, in the below code, the eval function evaluates `any` as a string and interprets to python's `any` built-in function.

```
>>> eval('any')
>>> <built-in function any>
```

On similar grounds, you could evaluate the intended function from a string as below.

```
def function_a(): 
    print('function A')

def function_b(): 
    print('function B')

function_to_run = eval('function_b')    # function_to_run is a callable now
function_to_run()
```

**Result**

```
function B
```

Comment: Use of `eval` should be highly discouraged. It's [dangerous and a bad practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1832940/why-is-using-eval-a-bad-practice).

Comment: @Jarvis agree. How do you think that code in the question is vulnerable to eval?

Answer (score -1):

you can set the default value in the function itself

```
def a(x=1):
    print(x)

def b(y=2):
    print(y)


chosen_function = random.choice(func_list)

chosen_function()
```

Comment: `chosen_function` is a string, not a callable